# Update database in the middle of the transaction, possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

```
 
 @Transactional
 public void start() {
  ...
  ...
  int result = entityManager
                .createQuery("update Users set name=" + value + " where user.id=5").executeUpdate();
  .....

 }
```

Above code gives javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException exception.

Update database in the middle of the transaction, possible ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

A.

I just wonder if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a runtime exception which is thrown *by the persistence provider when a transaction is required but is not active.* A transaction is required because the `start` method is annotated as transactional. To get rid of the exception, you'll have to investigate *why* the line is called out of a transaction context.

A database update *may* be possible during a (different) transaction. Depends on the tables that are locked by the active transaction and on the transaction strategy. But in this case, it looks like you *need* to activate a transaction *before* you enter the `start` method.

---

With JPA you'd do something like this:

```
em = emf.createEntityManager();
tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();   // now a transaction is active
start();      // call your method
// call other methods...
tx.commit();  // now the update is actually done
em.close();
```

Note - this is close to pseudo code, exception handling is missing in this example.

Comment: how ? an example please... Thanks.